# Android 9 AAC decoder outputs zero samples with ffmpeg-encoded files

Tags: android, android-mediacodec, aac, android-9.0-pie, mediaextractor

I have some automated tests that try to decode a few m4a files to PCM data using Android's `MediaDecoder` and `MediaExtractor`. The files are generated with various encoders: [fdk-aac](https://github.com/mstorsjo/fdk-aac), ffmpeg (with fdk or the default aac encoder), iOS.

On Android 9 the test fails for the clips created with `ffmpeg`, which results in empty PCM files. The same clips are decoded fine on older versions of Android.

I double checked my code and the decoding process goes as expected:

- I extract compressed data using `MediaExtractor`
- Enqueue it to the codec
- Dequeue the output buffer from the codec.

The issue is that by the time the last available input buffer is enqueued and the output buffer with `MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM` is dequeued, all output buffers are empty!

Then I noticed that the `MediaFormat` info extracted from the audio file with `MediaExtractor.getTrackFormat(int track)` contains an undocumented `"encoder-delay"` key.

**For android 8 and lower**, that key is only present for m4a clips encoded with the `iTunSMPB` tag info. Here's a summary of the values I get for my test files:

```
iOS-encoded file:           2112 frames
fdkaac with iTunSMPB tag:   2048 frames
fdkaac with ISO delay info: key not present
ffmpeg:                     key not present
ffmpeg (fdk):               key not present
```

**On Android 9**, instead, I get the following results:

```
iOS-encoded file:           2112 frames
fdkaac with iTunSMPB tag:   2048 frames
fdkaac with ISO delay info: 2048 frames
ffmpeg:                     45158 frames
ffmpeg (fdk):               90317 frames
```

It looks like something has changed and `MediaExtractor` is now able to retrieve the encoder delay for all the files under test. This is good in theory, since the files with no `"encoder-delay"` info do show a delay in the decoded PCM data (this was a known issue).

But... while the value for the **"fdkaac with ISO delay info"** case is correct and leads to a valid PCM file with no initial padding (finally!), the values for the ffmpeg-generated files look huge and likely wrong!

I know the real encoder delay values are 1024 for the **ffmpeg** case, and 2048 for the **ffmpeg (fdk)** case, and I think the high value for key in the extracted format is the reason why the file is empty.

In fact, if I try setting the `"encoder-delay"` key to 0 in the format just before passing it to `MediaCodec.configure(...)` I get the correct uncompressed data with the expected delay.

My guess at this point is that the `MediaExtractor` encoder delay value retrieval has some bug, but maybe there's something I am overlooking.

Since ffmpeg is quite popular, it's quite likely that many of my app users will try importing files generated with it, and at this point I can't see a foolproof solution to the issue.

Does anyone have a suggestion / workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I opened an issue on the android issue tracker:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/118398811

And for now I just implemented a workaround: when the "encoder-delay" value is present in the `MediaFormat` object and it's an impossibly high value, I just set it to zero. Something like:

```
if (format.containsKey("encoder-delay") && format.getInteger("encoder-delay") > THRESHOLD) {
    format.setInteger("encoder-delay", 0);
}
```

**NB:** This means the initial gap will not be trimmed away, but for M4a files that don't have such info this is already the case on pre-android-9 devices.